# LoadError: cannot load such file -- capistrano/perforce.rb

Tags: perforce, capistrano3

I want to deploy capistrano with perforce
i make following changes in cap file

```
set :scm, :perforce
set :p4port, "xxxx:6666"
set :p4client, "xxx"
set :p4user, "xxx"
set :p4passwd, "xxx"
set :p4client_root, "xxx"
set :p4, "/bin/p4"
set :repository, "xxx/..." 

# Perforce specifics

set :deploy_to, "/xxx"

and from cap file commented the following lines
#require "capistrano/scm/git"
#install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git
```

**can i get a perforce plugin?**

Comment: Are you looking for P4Ruby? https://swarm.workshop.perforce.com/projects/perforce-software-p4ruby/

Comment: when capistrano is installed then a capfile is get created. in this file scm plugin is get loaded e.g. the git plugin loaded like this.                                            require "capistrano/scm/git"
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git                                                                       where is plugin for perforce

Comment: You may find this KB article helpful: http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB/3366

Comment: yes i seen this article already but they are using scm as perforce and in capistrano there is no plugin available with this name.